# ios call back block return value

Tags: ios, callback, block

I am testing the call back and block function.

I'm using the objective-c in iOS.

I write a call back method name is  "dosomethingProcessWithCompletion".

**dosomethingProcessWithCompletion** do something , then it will get the NSMutableDictionary value, I will use the nsmutabledictionary value to check something and return the value yes or no.

If the value is yes(------- AAAAA-------), I need break the

for( NSInteger i = 0 ; i < myAry.count; i++ ).. for loop .

and return the yes using tryToCallBlockMethod method.

If the value is no, the for loop will run to last item and return the no using tryToCallBlockMethod method.

But I don't known how to write the call back return value .

have anyone can give some hand?

My code below:

My AppTool declare:

```
 typedef BOOL(^DoMyProcessCompletion)(NSMutableDictionary *completeresult);
 + (void) dosomethingProcessWithCompletion:(NSURL*)theUrl andUserPsd:(NSString*)psd withCompletion:(DoMyProcessCompletion) completion{

 .....
 ....
 ..
 NSMutableDictionary *resultDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 if( something == YES ){

  [resultDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"resultDicKey"];
     [resultDic setObject:myData forKey:@"myDataDicKey"];
       }else{
 [resultDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"resultDicKey"];
     [resultDic setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"myDataDicKey"];
       }
  completion(resultDic)
 }
```

My use and implement function is below:

```
 -(BOOL) tryToCallBlockMethod{
     for( NSInteger i = 0 ; i < myAry.count; i++ ){
          userPsd = myAry[i];    
         [AppTool dosomethingProcessWithCompletion:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl] andUserPsd:userPsd withCompletion:^(NSMutableDictionary *completeResult) {

             BOOL result = [[completeResult objectForKey:@"resultDicKey"] boolValue];
             if( result == YES){
                 //------- AAAAA-------
                 //------- if result is YES, will break the for look , and  tryToCallBlockMethod will return YES.
                 return YES;
             }else{
                 //------- BBBBBBB-------
                 return NO;
             }
         }];
     }
 }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you totally misunderstand the usage of the block. Block is usually used for an async way, how could an async process break a loop?  If you want some checks could break loop, you should not use block, just use normal sync process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return boolean as below while you have used the **Block** inside the fuction.

```
-(void) tryToCallBlockMethod:(void(^)(BOOL isResult))callback{
        if( result == YES){
                    callback(YES)
                 return YES;
             }else{
                    callback(NO)

             }
}
```